# JQuery : recover IP information in https

Tags: jquery, ssl, web, https, ip

I need to know the country corresponding to the user's ip, and it use to work with this jquery api :

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
            var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
            callback(countryCode);
        });
```

Butsince I add the SSL certificate to my webpage, it doesn't work anymore. I tried to put the ipinfo.io link in https:// instead but you have to pay to enable the https version of this api. So I would like to know if someone knows a free way to have these information in https.
Thanks

Comment: you can delegate your ip lookup to your webserver (it will made the request for the client and send the response back).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by delegating to the webserver...

Comment: you implement the logic of getting ip info on the server side, YOUR server will make the call to ipinfo.io and send it back to the client...

Comment: Alright ! So in the php code ? But do you know how to do that ?

Comment: [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is your friend

Comment: oh, it's to difficult for me, I don't understand anything. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate that job to the server. Implementing such a thing with PHP-curl is easy (I didn't test it, but I think it works):

```
<?php 
        $url="http://ipinfo.io/".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        // create curl resource 
        $curl = curl_init(); 
        // set the target url
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        //return as string 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        // store response body
        $output = curl_exec($curl); 
        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
        curl_close($curl);  
        echo $output;
```

storing ip infos in session to avoid calling the webservice everytime would be clever but it's out of the scope of the question.

Comment: I need more informations "it didn't work" is not a good description

Comment: it returned the ip address

Comment: if you are testing from your local network, that's normal as there is no geo-ip for local IP address... On my docker container I got something like this: `{ ip: "172.17.0.1",hostname: "ip-172-17-0-1.eu-central-1.compute.internal"}` (only IP and hostname as I'm on a lan). It won't work on Lan, but will online...

Comment: @n00dI3, I tried it again, now it displays me the right array in localhost, but  boot(false) online :/